# Gack - Failed to find definition for dependency: proxy-compat/setKey

Tags: gack, user-profile

I get the following error when I try to click on my personal profile settings in my developer account

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: 27388038)
>
> Error in $A.getCallback() [Assertion Failed!: Failed to find definition for dependency: proxy-compat/setKey : undefined [Error creating components one:densityUserSettings in one:userProfileCard]]
>   eval()@

Comment: Which page exactly? Do you have any addons installed in your browser? Anything on the Developer Console (F12)?